# ImageView overlaps BottomBar but it doesn't get displayed

Tags: android

I'm using a library named [AHBottomNavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) and what I want to achieve in my layout is add an ImageView **on top** of the bottom bar.

So I wrapped the bottomBar inside a `FrameLayout` and added an `ImageView` :

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
         android:id="@+id/bb_bottom_bar_navigation"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:contentDescription="Take Photo"
        android:layout_width="32dp" android:layout_height="32dp"  />

</FrameLayout>
```

and while it seems to work (and I can confirm that on three devices I have already tested I can see the image) when I test it on devices that run android 5.0 or later the image is not there!

I have tried different pngs, adding background color to the `ImageView` but still no result. 
If I use `uiautomatorView` I can see the View is in the position I want it  and takes the space I have already defined in the xml.

Obviously there's something that intercepts the view from drawing, but I don;t know such a mechanism on android. I tried digging through the code of the library but don't knowing what I'm searching for didn't help.

Any ideas ? (cause I'm out of ideas)

Comment: FrameLayout overlaps it's child views. If you want to show views vertically or in any other orientation, use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: No, this is not my case. I really want the `ImageView` to overlap the bottom bar. Why is this not possible for devices with > 5.0 android ?

Comment: Try using RelativeLayout with elevation in ImageView.